# Conditional Rendering is not working in the tbody in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render one conditional JSX.So, I am not able to render that

Here I have the fixed height of the tbody.

maxHeight : 120px;

```
<tbody className="text-center" style={jobsHeight}>
      {props.jobList && props.jobList.length > 0 && props.jobList.map((item, key) => {
        return areJobsPresent ? (
          <tr key={key}>
            <td className="noborder">{item.technology}</td>
            <td className="font-weight-bold noborder">{item.resumeCount}</td>
            <td title={item.jobTitle} className="noborder">
              {item.jobTitle}
            </td>
            <td className="font-weight-bold noborder">{item.totalScore}</td>
            <td className="font-weight-bold noborder">{item.avgScore}</td>
          </tr>
        ) :
          <tr>
            <td>
              No Jobs Found. please create a Job
            </td>
          </tr>
      })}
```

So here before render I am computing the `areJobSabsent` flag.

```
 const areJobsPresent = props.jobList.length > 0
```

So, here I tried with this way. if there is not data present then I want to show a tr with the message. So, where I am wrong ? can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Where does this come from `areJobsPresent` ?

Comment: I have just updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you have already checked for the condition before calling map, so map never executes and the internal condition never gets checked. You have to use a ternary expression outside the map call

```
<tbody className="text-center" style={jobsHeight}>
      {props.jobList && props.jobList.length > 0 ? props.jobList.map((item, key) =>         <tr key={key}>
            (<td className="noborder">{item.technology}</td>
            <td className="font-weight-bold noborder">{item.resumeCount}</td>
            <td title={item.jobTitle} className="noborder">
              {item.jobTitle}
            </td>
            <td className="font-weight-bold noborder">{item.totalScore}</td>
            <td className="font-weight-bold noborder">{item.avgScore}</td>
          </tr>)
        ) :
          <tr>
            <td>
              No Jobs Found. please create a Job
            </td>
          </tr>
      }
```

Comment: Is that the concept of "hoisting" as checking condition before calling it?

Comment: No, this is a misunderstanding of the logical `&&` operator. If the left side of the operator is false, the right side never gets executed.

Comment: There is no return in this ?

Comment: I think there is some syntactical issue here

Comment: sorry need to remove that bracket

Comment: Inside a lambda method with no curly brackets return is implicit. i.e. `() => (this is returned)`